# How Do I get a particular element in the XML I receive (From a third Party)?

Tags: xml, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a XML response which I have received as output of a System link(Infor XA related)process. The response would look like below:

```
 **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<System-Link hostVersion="1.0" version="1.0">
    -<Response hasWarnings="false" hasErrors="true" systemTimeZoneOffset="-5:00" 
    systemTimestamp="2017-08-22 03:37:01.115" 
    workHandle="-1e4c99eb:15dff5e8e61:-796d" 
    sessionHandle="-1e4c99eb:15dff5e8e61:-7970">
    -<UpdateResponse actionSucceeded="false" 
    requestedDomainClass="com.mapics.epdm.BillOfMaterialComponent" 
    name="updateObject_BillofMaterial Component_1">
    -<Exception name="com.pjx.eScript.ObjectNotFoundException">
    -<Text>
    <![CDATA[Object does not exist]]>
    </Text>
    -<Message type="error">
    -<Text>
    <![CDATA[The named object was not found.]]>  
    </Text>
    </Message>
    </Exception>
    </UpdateResponse>
    <UpdateResponse actionSucceeded="true" 
    requestedDomainClass="com.mapics.epdm.BillOfMaterialComponent" 
    name="updateObject_BillofMaterial Component_2"/>
    <UpdateResponse actionSucceeded="true" 
    requestedDomainClass="com.mapics.epdm.BillOfMaterialComponent" 
    name="updateObject_BillofMaterial Component_3"/>
    <UpdateResponse actionSucceeded="true" 
    requestedDomainClass="com.mapics.epdm.BillOfMaterialComponent" 
    name="updateObject_BillofMaterial Component_4"/>
    <UpdateResponse actionSucceeded="true" 
    requestedDomainClass="com.mapics.epdm.BillOfMaterialComponent" 
    name="updateObject_BillofMaterial Component_5"/>
    </Response>
    </System-Link>**
```

So I need to get the 'actionSucceeded' value of all the responses(Which would be on one transaction). If it is false, then I would like to get the .  Is there a RPG XML function to get this? Basically I need to know if my request was success or not by checking the response(as shown above) and not doing a Scan through the entire request

Comment: There is sax processing available in RPGLE.  and an interesting rpg-into op code.  Me I would from rpgle call a java class to parse xml probably using a pull parser in the java class for speed.

Comment: @danny117 Why would a pull parser be faster than a SAX parser? It has a slightly more convenient interface but also has to parse the document from front to back. XML-SAX uses Xerces which is pretty fast (and probably fast enough anyway). There is also the option to use the expat xml parser in RPG by using the port from Scott Klement.

And you would also have to step out from RPG to Java (starting a VM etc) which is not very convenient at all.

Comment: pull  parsers simply read the file from start to end.  Sax parsers have some intelligence built in that slow things down a bit.

Comment: starting a VM is a big hit.  But someone already invented the wheel for parsing xml in java.  I'm pushing java over rpgle today.  How about a free xlsx to csv java class that runs on the as400?  That's why java is so important to your success.

Comment: Thanks Danny and Mihael. I used XML-INTO for this. Basically, I created a DS with the same format as XML, and used a XML-INTO and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the opcode XML-SAX to parse the xml document. See the IBM Knowledge Center for more info on the opcode, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/zzxmlsa.htm .

I use XML-SAX to parse an xml document (configuration file) in one of my projects, see [BlueDroplet XML Configuration Provider](https://bitbucket.org/m1hael/bluedroplet/src/be7b76f6e69a97dc5efa20b4c1217285225bbaf4/xml_config_provider.rpgle) .

And my opinion: Don't use Java for anything you can easily also do in RPG when your main code base is already RPG.